# PHP while loop curl IFisset error

Tags: php, mysql, curl

Here is my script

```
$id=$row['user_id'];
if (isset($_GET['trea'])){

$ch = curl_init();  // Initialise a cURL handle


// Setting proxy option for cURL
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPPROXYTUNNEL, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, '$proxy_ip');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 100);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $final);

$results = curl_exec($ch);  // Execute a cURL request
curl_close($ch);   
 echo $results;
 }
?>

<form action='admin.php' method='get'>
<input type=submit name="trea" value="<?php echo $id ?>">
```

Now if i click on submit button on my page.It sends CURL request to all the rows instead of that particular row.so i tried to change this

> if (isset($_GET['trea'])){

to

> if (isset($_GET['$id'])){

and

> `<input type=submit name="trea" value="<?php echo $id ?>">`

to

> ```
> <input type=submit name="$id" value="<?php echo $id ?>">
> ```

And when i try to submit the button.It does nothing.What am i doing wrong? i want to run CURL request on that particular row when i click on submit button of that row

Comment: The field "trea" should probably be a hidden field <input type="hidden" name="trea" value="<?php echo $id; ?>" /> and remove name/value from submit

Comment: Note that variable interpolation doesn't happen inside single quotes.  So in `$_GET['$id']` and `'$proxy_ip'`, you will not get variable substitution.  Instead, use `$_GET[$id]`.  Might be part of your issues.

Comment: @drew010 it works fine with proxy. even with those single quotes it showed me proper PROXY ipwhen i sent a request to server.

Comment: @Trent so if i do that will it preform curl function on that particular row with that ID? and if so then show should i add in this place if (isset($_GET['$id'])){
 or keep it as it is?

Comment: First thing's first... Comment out all your curl logic - just work on getting the correct values in your variables. If you change trea to a hidden field, echo out $_GET['trea'] if it's set. What value do you get?